# Two orthogonal vectors.

Tags: vectors

Can someone explain graphically why scalar product of two orthogonal vectors is 0?
Can someone draw it? I understand through calculation but don't know how to express it graphically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **dot** product of two vectors is $0$ if and only if they're orthogonal. In general, given $u,v \in \mathbb{R}^m$, we have $$u \cdot v = \sum_{i=1}^{m} u_iv_i$$ for the scalar components of $u$ and $v$. It can be shown that this is equivalent, in two dimensions with generalizations in higher dimensions, to $u \cdot v = ||u||||v|| \cos \theta$.
 In two dimensions, you can prove this simply with the law of cosines.
Take two vectors, make a triangle with a third vector in terms of the first two, and see what happens.

[image]

Thus, if $u \cdot v = 0$, $\cos \theta = 0$, so $\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: What is the difference between dot and scalar product?

Comment: @Junior A scalar product is, given $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, $\alpha u $ is the vector with components $\alpha u_i$.

Comment: ok thanks for explanation.

Comment: Scalar product and dot product can in fact be used interchangeably.

Comment: @Anthony Peter Can't edit my comment anymore, so I deleted it. The answer is correct, but the comment about the term "scalar product" is wrong. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product